# Slide panel horizontal with jQuery and css3

Tags: jquery, performance, css

I would like make a slider panel which slide from right border screen to left. 
I want the slide starts move when I "hover" the panel caller : tab. And when the panel moves, it pushes the tab with him. I have this code :

html

```
<div id="panel">
<div class="content"><!-- Content --></div>
</div>
<div id="tab">hit me for show panel</div>
```

css

```
#tab {
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:100px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#panel {
        position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:50px;
    background-color:#999999;
    height:500px;
    width:0;
}
#panel .content {
    width:290px;
    margin-left:70px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() { 
        $('#tab').hover(function(event) {
        var panel = $('#panel');
        if (panel.hasClass('open')) {       //condition error
            panel.removeClass('open');
            $('.content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#panel').stop().animate({
                    width: '0',
                    opacity: 0.0
                }, 500)
            })
        } else {
            panel.addClass('open');
            $('#panel').stop().animate({
                width: '400',
                opacity: 1
            }, 500, function() { 
                $('.content').fadeIn('slow'); 
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

The problem is when I leave the tab with the mouse cursor for "hover" panel, the panel disappears. And I want the panel stay open as long as I "hover" on both : tab AND panel. How I do that ?

Comment: edited the answer . let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see snippet below

i've changed your JQ a bit. first, i've removed the `if` and added a `mouseOut` function on the visible `panel` ( with class `open` )

so when you hover the `tab` , the `panel` appears , but nothing happens on `hover out` . instead, the panel hides again if you `mouseout` from it. so, as long as you are with your cursor on the `panel` , it will stay open.

as a side note, you can delete the parts with `addClass('open')` and `removeClass('open')` and in the `mouseout()` method just change from `#panel.open` to just `#panel` or use the variable `panel` . you can do this if you don't want to style the `.open` class in CSS or something like that.

hope it helps. let me know :)

```js
        $('#tab').hover(function(event) {
        var panel = $('#panel');
            panel.addClass('open');
          
            $('#tab').stop().animate({
                'right': '400',
           
               
            }, 500)
            $('#panel').stop().animate({
                width: '400',
                opacity: 1
               
            }, 500, function() { 
                $('.content').fadeIn('slow'); 
            });
   
         $('#panel.open').mouseout(function() { 
               $(this).removeClass('open');
               
            $('.content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $("#tab").removeClass("moveme")
                $('#panel').stop().animate({
                    width: '0',
                    opacity: 0.0
             }, 500)
                 $('#tab').stop().animate({
                'right': '0',
           
               
            }, 500)
      
     
     }); 
    }); 
           });
```

```css
#tab {
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:100px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#panel {
        position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:50px;
    background-color:#999999;
    height:500px;
    width:0;

}
#panel .content {
    width:290px;
    margin-left:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
<div class="content"><!-- Content --></div>
</div>
<div id="tab">hit me for show panel</div>
```

Comment: Ok is that, but a little thing : I would like the panel pushes the tab with him.

Comment: well you didn't say that :)) let me change it a bit

Comment: @PierreDommerc edited the answer . let me know if it works for you

Comment: I have just tested your code and sometimes this is totally bug : When I go out the panel and I come back quicly and again the panel stay open while i'am out :(

Comment: i cannot replicate that bug but it might be because of the delay